# How to declare some methods after using Class.forname() in Java

Tags: java, reflection

I use Class.forname() to create an instance dynamically using this code:

```
String className = "models." + category;
Class c = Class.forName(className);
Object tuple = c.newInstance();
```

But after that, I found I cannot call some methods in the class. I cannot use tuple.setName() or the other methods.

How can declare that the class c can call some methods in java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have an interface you can cast that class to:

```
 MyInterface tuple =  (MyInterface) c.newInstance();
 tuple.setName("Bilbo");
```

Failing that, you need to continue to use reflection:

```
 Method setName = c.getMethod("setName", String.class);
 setName.invoke(tuple, "Bilbo");
```